# Cloudant create same _id document cross databases failed due to Conflict conflict Document update conflict

Tags: cloudant

I had two dbs which some documents had same '_id' value such as unique id. But I create document for the second database which returned 409 Client Error: Conflict conflict Document update conflict.

```
with Document(whitelist_dbname, id) as document:
    current_time = dt.datetime.now().isoformat()
    if document.exists():
        print 'Update whitelist item "{0}"'.format(id)
        document['type'] = 'id'
        document['expired_date'] = whitelist_item['expiry']
        document['contact'] = whitelist_item['contact']
        document['updated_time'] = current_time
        document.save()
    else:
        print 'Creating whitelist item "{0}"'.format(id)
        new_item = {
            '_id': id,
            'type': 'id',
            'contact': whitelist_item['contact'],
            'expired_date': whitelist_item['expiry'],
            'created_time': current_time,
            'updated_time': current_time,
        }
        whitelist_dbname.create_document(new_item, throw_on_exists=False)
```

My database `whitelists` had same _id value before I ran this python code.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, the _id field in a Cloudant document must be unique to the database which contains it. If you choose to create your own _id sequence (which is a valid thing to want to do), you shoulder the responsibility to ensure that it really is unique. This might be fine for a given database, but may get complicated if you want to replicate between two (or more) databases. Now the _id sequence must be unique across all replicas.

You haven't really provided the necessary information to be able to help -- your code isn't what we'd need to see, we'd need to see the data.

Cloudant ensures that it is impossible for two different documents in the same database to have the same _id.

Note that a *conflict* (409) is more subtle than that. An update conflict is a breach of consistency. A Cloudant document also has a revision id, *_rev*. When you update an existing document, you need to provide both the _id and the _rev, stipulating precisely which revision of a document you are trying to update. Recall that a Cloudant document is really a tree of revisions (somewhat like a git repository).

This means that Cloudant will only allow you to update a leaf revision. If you try to update an internal (non-leaf) revision, your request will be rejected with a 409.

Here's a good primer on the document tree and how to manipulate it:

https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2017/1/1/the-tree-behind-cloudants-documents-and-how-to-use-it.html